# Can't get Aptana Studio 3 to run Python code as PyDev

Tags: python, pydev, aptana

I just installed Aptana Studio to start and learn to code in Python. However, even my Hello World doesn't run, beacuse I run it in PyDev mode, as suggested.

I use Python 3.5.2, and I have configured the interpreter.
If I click onto "run", all it gives me is this:
[run function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxRcr.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try PyCharm instead.

Answer (score 0):

The PyDev version included with Aptana Studio 3 is pretty ancient. Please consider getting either LiClipse (http://liclipse.com) which has PyDev builtin or get the latest Eclipse and install PyDev in it (following instructions from: http://www.pydev.org/download.html).

Also, make sure you read the getting started manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html